How do I connect to inherited signals in PyQt?
I have a PyQt application where I need to connect signals inherited from a parent class in a few child classes.
Let's say my BaseClass defines two signals a and b:
class BaseClass(QObject):
    signal_a = pyqtSignal()
    signal_b = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @abstractmethod
    def connect_signals(self):
        pass

And other child classes, e.g. WidgetA, which inherit from BaseClass, decide to which signals to connect:
class WidgetA(QWidget, BaseClass):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.connect_signals()

    @override
    def connect_signals(self):
        self.signal_a.connect(self.handler_a)
    
    @pyqtSlot()
    def handler_a(self):
        print("handler_a")

I get the following error when trying to connect the signals:
QObject::connect: No such signal BaseClass::signal_a()
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
TypeError: connect() failed between WidgetA.signal_a[] and handler_a()

I suspect that the issue is that I'm inheriting from QObject twice, but I'd like to know if there's an alternative way to achive this control over which signals to connect.

PyQt (and PySide, IIRC) does not allow multiple inheritance of more than one QObject based class, and QWidget already inherits from QObject. You also never called the __init__ of QWidget, which is inappropriate and will eventually cause other exceptions. Change the inheritance of BaseClass to object (or just remove the parentheses, as it's implicit), and use super().__init__() also in the init of WidgetA, which will automatically take care of proper super class initialization.

Thanks. I'll edit the super().__init__() because it wasn't supposed to come out like that in the question. Inheriting from object was the answer that I was looking for.

You're welcome. Note object is the base class for all objects in Python (all classes eventually inherit from it, check the class __mro__), that's why you may omit the (object) in the class declaration. Also consider that the slot decorator is almost always unnecessary, so you can avoid it: it's only relevant for some complex thread-related scenarios, when QMetaObject introspection is required (eg: Qt Designer plugins), or in the rare case of extremely high numbers of objects (in the order of tens of thousands objects and connections) for which there's a slight performance improvement.
